# abas sobrepondo no foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, lógica

Preciso que o foreach funcione corretamente :
Para que não tenhamos dúvida aqui esta o código normal:

```
<!-- Tab v2 -->
    <div class="tabs alternative">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#sample-2a" data-toggle="tab">Sample Heading 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#sample-2b" data-toggle="tab">Sample Heading 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#sample-2c" data-toggle="tab">Sample Heading 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#sample-2d" data-toggle="tab">Sample Heading 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="sample-2a">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img src="assets/img/fillers/filler1.jpg" alt="filler image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h3 class="no-margin no-padding">Humanitatis Per Seacula</h3>
                        <p>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus,
                            qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothicas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="sample-2b">
                <p>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui
                    sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem
                    modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="sample-2c">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img src="assets/img/fillers/filler3.jpg" alt="filler image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h3 class="no-margin no-padding">Mirum Est Notare</h3>
                        <p>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus,
                            qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothicas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="sample-2d">
                <p>Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque
                    fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, consectetur id.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Donec eget orci metus</li>
                    <li>Ante ac interdum ullamcorper</li>
                    <li>Vivamus imperdiet condimentum</li>
                    <li>Pellentesque fermentum</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Tab v2 -->
```

Esse código gera esse efeito :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo, quando faço o loop fica sobrepondo as abas.

Como estou fazendo:

```
<!-- Tab v2 -->

    <div class="tabs alternative">
        <?php $x=0; foreach($programacao_mes as $value):;?>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

            <li <?php echo ($value->programacao_id == 1) ? "class='active'" : ""   ?>>
                <a href="#sample-<?php echo $x?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $value->programacao_titulo;?></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div <?php echo ($value->programacao_id == 1) ? "class='tab-pane fade in active' id='sample-$x' " : "class='tab-pane fade in' " ?> >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img src="assets/img/fillers/filler1.jpg" alt="filler image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h3 class="no-margin no-padding"><?php echo $value->programacao_titulo;?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $value->programacao_post;?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
         <?php $x++; endforeach;?>
    </div>

<!-- End Tab v2 -->
```

Que gera esse efeito totalmente errada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que provavelmente estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Sem entender como é a regra css ou javascript(se existir), é inviável dizer como consertar. Pode ser apenas css ou pode estar com css correto e aplicando o “foreach” em local errado..

Comment: Estou achando que estou aplicando o foreach no local errado, só que não sei onde aplicar. Já tentei em vários lugares e nada nada;

Comment: Por isso tem que entender como é a regra para uso do efeito de abas. Deve ter alguma documentação da library que  está usando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você fizer desta forma, dará certo:

```
<!-- Tab v2 -->
<div class="tabs alternative">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <?php $x=0; foreach($programacao_mes as $value){ ?>
            <a href="#sample-<?php echo $x; ?>" data-toggle="tab">Sample Heading <?php echo $x; ?></a>
            <?php $x++; } ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <?php $b=0; foreach($programacao_mes as $value){ ?>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="sample-<?php echo $b; ?>">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img src="assets/img/fillers/filler1.jpg" alt="filler image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h3 class="no-margin no-padding">Humanitatis Per Seacula</h3>
                    <p>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus,
                        qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothicas.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $b++; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Tab v2 -->
```

Coloquei $x, $b, para contagem de quantos registros são no seu foreach(), e ai identificar onde cada conteúdo deve estar.

E note que são dois foreach(), o primeiro deverá trazer as categorias em que estão cada conteúdo, e o segundo, seus respectivos conteúdos, com base nas categorias selecionadas.

Comment: Perfeito, a lógica foi ótima, aprendi muito com isso.
Fiz uns ajustes aqui e pronto.

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente você deve estar aplicando o `foreach` no lugar errado.

Repare que a tag `<UL>` significa "unordenate list", ou seja, marcação de lista não-ordenada. Ao colocar essa tag dentro do foreach você está replicando as listas, cada uma com um único item.

A tag `<LI>` significa "list item" e somente ela é que deve aparecer dentro do `foreach`, criando assim uma única lista (UL) com tantos items quanto forem necessários.